# Golang Array Pointer

Tags: arrays, go

I want to elucidate this behavior in Golang,
Why when you take the memory reference on array and you change values from this reference nothing change in the referencing array.

One example :

```
var t [5]int
printType(t,"t")
p := &t
printType(p,"p")
x := *p
x[0] = 4
printType(x,"x")
printType(p,"p")
printType(t,"t")
```

This code return

```
[t] Type:[5]int Kind:array Adr:%!p([5]int=[0 0 0 0 0]) Value:([0 0 0 0 0])
[p] Type:*[5]int Kind:ptr Adr:0xc4200142d0 Value:(&[0 0 0 0 0])
[x] Type:[5]int Kind:array Adr:%!p([5]int=[4 0 0 0 0]) Value:([4 0 0 0 0])
[p] Type:*[5]int Kind:ptr Adr:0xc4200142d0 Value:(&[0 0 0 0 0])
[t] Type:[5]int Kind:array Adr:%!p([5]int=[0 0 0 0 0]) Value:([0 0 0 0 0])
```

you can see the memory address is the same but the value "4" is not present.

Method printType

```
func printType(i interface {},message string) {
   k := reflect.TypeOf(i).Kind().String()
   fmt.Printf("[%s] Type:%T Kind:%s Adr:%[2]p Value:(%[2]v)\n",message,i,k)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Okay found it, the operator ":=" allocate an new memory address.

No, it doesn't allocate anything.

`var t [5]int` is a value. Note that according to spec `[5]int` if full type name in this case. You can think of it as of a struct with 5 `int` fields. Line `x := *p` makes dereferencing pointer to the `t` (a value). Assigning value creates a copy of it. If you want to pass a "reference" to `t` make slice of it: `t[:]`.

Answer (score -1):

Okay found it, the operator ":=" allocates a new memory address.